# SVG file : How to get Path markup datas after convert a PNG file into a SVG file with Inkscape?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm asking if there would be a tool to convert a PNG file into a SVG file where I could get the Path markup. I have tried with Inkscape but when I edit the SVG file I can't find the path markup, there is only "binary" datas.

SVG file path markup example :
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData

Is anyone have a idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "convert a PNG file into a SVG file"?  It sounds like you might just be putting your PNG into an SVG file.  That doesn't automatically turn it into a path.  It is just a bitmap embedded in an SVG.  It stays a bitmap.

What it sounds like you want, is to convert your bitmap to a vector.  That process is commonly called a "bitmap trace".  Inkscape has a feature to do that.  Select the PNG and do a Path->Trace Bitmap...

How well it works will depend on your image.  Logos generally work well.  Photos usually don't.

Once you have done the trace, save the SVG file and you will be able to get the path data then.

Comment: ok, I have only executed a "save as" into a SVG file after loaded my PNG file. I didn't know that the original bitmap data were embedded into the file. After doing a Path->Trace Bitmap, it works fine, I can find the path markup section in the SVG file. Thanks a lot !!! My goal is to convert some png icon I need to work with some google maps api objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a raster image into a vector image. Though there are programs like vector magic that try to make it into a vector image looking as close as possible as the raster image by looking at shapes of similar colors.